# Build a string changing a variable in each loop iteration and joining all of them

Tags: c#

I need to build a my sql query which is basically at his core is similar to the following:

```
select something from {myCurrentTable} where some condition
```

This query must be repeated N times where N is unknown and put in a union.

I need to change the value of `myCurrentTable` every iteration so i would do something like this:

```
foreach(string table in myTables)
{
    queryTot += $"SELECT something from {table} where some condition";
    if(!lastIteration)
       queryTot += " union ";
}
```

Is there any function i can use to get rid of the explicit loop?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to get rid of the loop? Have you thought about `string.Join(" UNION ", ...)` ?

Comment: For what it's worth you may want `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`: the latter deduplicates the results.

Comment: @BurnsBA mainly cause i want to make the part of the function i'm working on less "verbose"

Comment: Please be aware this code is also susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Also, what is wrong with using a loop in the first place? Any code you do use (like the `string.Join` answer below) is internally still using a loop.

Comment: @DavidG Depends where `myTables` is being set. If  `myTables` is a whitelisted collection of table names then it's completely fine.

Comment: @DavidG there is nothing wrong in the loop, and i know that string join does a loop internally. I just wanted to make this part of the function more readable

Comment: I don't think the accepted answer is more readable than what you have here (even though it's probably something I may have written too), in fact, I'd say it's more complicated since it uses string.Join *and* Linq. I'd say using a StringBuilder and your existing loop is probably the simplest and most readable.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Possibly, but it's not that hard to start sneaking in nefarious things.

Comment: The thing that's nice about using `string.Join` is that you don't need to be concerned with checking for the last iteration, and it also works with a single table :). With the loop approach, both these need to be accounted for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ `Select` to project the tables into SQL `select` statements, then `string.Join` to add a `union` between each one:

```
string query = string.Join(
    " union ",
    myTables.Select(table => $"SELECT something from {table} where some condition"));
```

Using `string.Join` rather than a manual loop means that the `union`s are correctly inserted without having to check for the last iteration, or check whether the `myTables` collection only contains a single item.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used string.Join in the past but i didn't thought i could have combined with LINQ Select.

Comment: @DanieleSartori `Select` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` here, and `string.Join` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) that accepts `IEnumerable<string>` as the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you concatenate strings in a loop in an undeterministic count, you should consider using `StringBuilder` instead of regular String.

Since a string is an immutable data type in C#, when you combine two or more strings, a new string is produced. If you append a series of characters to a string (like in your example), you will recreate the same string in memory multiple times..

An alternative approach is modifying a StringBuilder instance which does not result in the creation of a new instance in memory, hence it's recommended in the case you describe.